# SVG coordinates

Tags: javascript, svg

Please see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DgMDV/1/)

```
sample output:
offset based on svg x:12 y:34
mouse click based on screen x:22 y:38
mouse coord based on svg x:10 y:4
```

The above sample output is generated when I click on the rectangle on the top-left corner.

As far as I understood, getScreenCTM interface provides the transformation matrix for the element (svg here).  I got it as the first line. Second line indicate the mouse coordinate based on the screen coordinate. When I apply the transformation matrix to the mouse click, I expect the point will be translated to svg coordinate. That value is the 3 rd line above. I am not sure that it is correct. The rectangle has a y coordinate 10, and the click event is only availbake within the rectangle. So how could the mouse coord based on svg go below 10??

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<h1>sdsd</h1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" height="200">
    <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" >
        <!-- Draw the axes of the original coordinate system -->
        <line x1="0" y1=".5" x2="400" y2=".5" />
        <line x1=".5" y1="0" x2=".5" y2="150" />
    </g>

    <g >
        <rect class="drag resize" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="50" fill="#c66" />
    </g>
</svg>

    <h2 id="op"></h2> 

          <script type="text/javascript" src="vb.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var svg   = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var svgNS = svg.getAttribute('xmlns');
var pt    = svg.createSVGPoint();
var el1 = document.getElementsByTagName('rect')[0];

var log_svgcursorPoint,
    log_mouseclick,
    log_mousecoord;


function svgcursorPoint(evt){
    pt.x = evt.clientX; pt.y = evt.clientY;
    var a = svg.getScreenCTM();
    log_svgcursorPoint = "offset based on svg"+ " x:" + a.e +" y:" + a.f;
    var b = a.inverse();
    return pt.matrixTransform(b);
};

    (function(el){
        el.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
            log_mouseclick = "mouse click based on screen"+ " x:" + e.clientX +" y:" + e.clientY ;
            var svgmouse   = svgcursorPoint(e);    
            log_mousecoord = "mouse coord based on svg"+ " x:" + svgmouse.x +" y:" +svgmouse.y;
            document.getElementById('op').innerHTML = log_svgcursorPoint + "<br>" + log_mouseclick + "<br>" + log_mousecoord;
        },false);
    })(el1);
```

Comment: I'm seeing `mouse coord based on svg x:12 y:12` when I click on the top left corner in Firefox 4.0.2pre.  What browser are you seeing these results in?

Comment: It's possible it's just a browser bug, in 11.0.696.57 beta I also get `mouse coord based on svg x:12 y:12`.

Comment: thanks robert.. i will update and try... thanks a lot

Comment: seems like a webkit bug, which is fixed recently.. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27183 .. Yet to try on firefox as there is not native (stable) build for linux 64 bit machine

Comment: @bsreekanth I just use the [4.0 nightly](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-2.0/), there's nothing going on on that branch other than security fixes so it's pretty stable - just unzip and go :)

Comment: wish it were that easy :-) .. I tried stable for 4.1, then initially got an error " libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", then i added it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not the error is "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64". I tried both 32 bit and 64 bit stable earlier, now downloading "firefox-4.0.2pre.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" .. will update u.. thanks

Comment: ok.. firefox pre works great.. an interesting thing, zoom in/out is not allowed/working in FF for xhtml and svg files. Normal html is fine. anyway, I may worry about zoom factor later.. thanks for ur help..

Comment: @bsreekanth I'm on Fedora 14 64bit and I never have any problem with any of them :)  BTW, you should post your comment linking to the WebKit bug as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like a defect, depending on the browser zoom level. Raised an issue http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81995

Comment: Bug was assigned two years ago. Still nothing.